# How to read a file and load to a list in multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocess

A data file that i need to read is too big, and loading it to a list takes too long time. How can I use multiproces for this? In other words, I would like to parallelise the process file read and load to a list. Could you please help.

Basically, I have a data table, that I need to load to a list, something as below. Reading the file does not take time, but loading it to a list (myList) takes about 1 minute. So, is it possible to parallelise this:

```
def load_file(self, fileName):    
    time_start = time.time()
    myList = []
    # mySet = set()
    lines = self.read_file(fileName)
    # time_end = time.time()
    # print fileName, ": loaded ",  round(time_end-time_start, 4)," seconds" 
    for line in lines:  
        content = line.split()   
        myList.append(content)
    time_end = time.time()
    print fileName, ": ", len(myList), " rows loaded in", round(time_end-time_start, 4)," seconds"    
    return myList

def read_file(self, fileName): 
    filePath = self.data_directory + '\\' + fileName     
    try:
        with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            return lines
    except ValueError:
        print filePath + ' does not exist'
```

An adhoc way could be, (assume that the file has 2M lines, so len(lines) = 2M), load first 1M to myList1, and second 1M to myList2 in parallel, and then merge them, myList = myList1+myList2. But this doesn't sound like the best practice.

Comment: Are you sure you it really needs to be loaded into a list in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish. Typically, you can't read a file from disk any faster by splitting up the read among multiple processes.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?  And what exactly have you tried?  What problem did you run into?  If you e.g. ran out of memory multiprocess won't help.  If IO is the bottleneck, multiprocess won't help either.  In fact parallelizing file read rarely is a good idea.

Comment: I added details to the question above

Comment: If the file is a data table maybe you can try with [Pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.12.0).

Answer (score 1):

basically it is never a good idea call file.readlines() on a large file. I'm not sure what this lines does

```
self.read_file(fileName)
```

but I'm afraid it calls file.readlines().

Normally you do not want to have millions of lines of a large file in a list. That'll eat up your memory.

If you want to filter/transform the lines of a large file and then write the result lines into an other file, then use iterators instead of loading lines in a list.

I suggest try to organize your solution along these lines. This approach can easily handle files if size several gigabytes.

```
def split_lines(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:                
            yield line.split()

def process_splitted_lines(file):
    for splitted_line in split_lines(file):
        <do some other thing with splitted line>
        yield something

def write_result_lines(file):
    for something in process_splitted_lines(file):
        line = <do some other thing with something>
        <write line to resultfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing, that was fun, HA HA. I do not think this is very efficient :) Maybe there is another efficient way?

```py
import time
import multiprocessing

## Generate sample big file (~158Mo, 2M lines)
import random
chunks = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua".split()
with open(r"D:\testbig.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for i in range(2000000):
        for nch in range(random.randrange(5,20)):
            f.write(random.choice(chunks))
            f.write(" ")
        f.write("\n")

# Proposed direct way
fileName = "foo"
time_start = time.time()
myList = []
# mySet = set()
with open(r"D:\testbig.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
time_end = time.time()
print(fileName, ": loaded ",  round(time_end-time_start, 4)," seconds" )
for line in lines:  
    content = line.split()   
    myList.append(content)
time_end = time.time()
print(fileName, ": ", len(myList), " rows loaded in", round(time_end-time_start, 4)," seconds")
del myList

# Results:
## foo : loaded  0.9204  seconds
## foo :  2000000  rows loaded in 6.9107  seconds
## Press any key to continue . . .

# Workers method:
MAXPROCESS = 7
CHUNKLEN = 25600000

# The worker
def splitter(lines):
    myList = []
    for line in lines:
        content = line.split()
        myList.append(content)
    return myList

# The code has to be fully loaded, therefore in a function
def main():

    fileName = "foo"
    time_start = time.time()
    # Declare a pool of workers
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAXPROCESS)
    results = []
    with open(r"D:\testbig.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        while True:
            # Read an amount of lines (about CHUNKLEN bytes)
            lines = f.readlines(CHUNKLEN)
            # End of file breaks the loop
            if len(lines) == 0: break
            # Queue data to be processed
            results.append(pool.apply_async(splitter, (lines,)))
    time_end = time.time()
    print(fileName, ": loaded ",  round(time_end-time_start, 4)," seconds" )
    # Wait for queue to be processed
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # Put list pieces together
    myList = []
    for result in results:
        myList += result.get()

    time_end = time.time()
    print(fileName, ": ", len(myList), " rows loaded in", round(time_end-time_start, 4)," seconds")

main()

# Results:

# MAXPROCESS = 4
# CHUNKLEN = 8192
## foo : loaded  5.0075  seconds
## foo :  2000000  rows loaded in 11.0446  seconds
## Press any key to continue . . .

# MAXPROCESS = 7
# CHUNKLEN = 25600
## foo : loaded  6.0839  seconds
## foo :  2000000  rows loaded in 9.1102  seconds
## Press any key to continue . . .

# MAXPROCESS = 7
# CHUNKLEN = 25600000
## foo : loaded  3.1199  seconds
## foo :  2000000  rows loaded in 11.7622  seconds
## Press any key to continue . . .
```